# Matplotlib image show in PyQt GUI stops with Memory Error

Tags: memory, matplotlib, pyqt4

Problem:
I've got a PyQt4 GUI application which has to import 16-bit grayscale image data and do some calculations on the image. The Gui has some control elements and a QTabWidget() element with two tabs, where one displays the image and the other represents the calculation results in a table. The image representation is done using Matplotlib.

In my applications I should be able to open images of up to 10000x12500 pixels which corresponds to 250MB of image data. Unfotunately, with my application I am only able to open images of about the size of 130MB. When importing and displaying data bigger than 8000x8000 pixels, my application stops showing Memory Error. Although the image itself is 128MB of size, the windows task manager shows 694MB of used memory for the python task. Images of the size 8000x9000 pixels can't be displayed any more.

My computer has 4GB of RAM memory. I don't think that the problem occurs due to insuffiecient memory.

Question:
How can I enable my application to display images of sizes up to 10000x12500 pixels grayscale 16-bit? Is there a Matplotlib internal limitation I can modify?

I searched the net but didn't find any answer. The closest problem description to the one I have can be seen in [Excessive memory usage in Matplotlib imshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525706/excessive-memory-usage-in-matplotlib-imshow). But changing the display command from show() to draw() didn't help.

Thank you VERY MUCH for any help.

Answer (score 1):

`mapplotlib` is not efficient with memory with images, there are multiple internal copies of the data.

Unless you have a gargantuan screen (at 300ppi, your image is 33in x 42in), your images are going to be down-sampled when they are displayed.  I would suggest down-sampling your images to a size that is closer to the pixel count of the area it will actually be.  You probably will want to write something do to adaptive down sampling based on what the user can actually see.

related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183460/plot-really-big-file-in-python-5gb-with-x-axis-offset) [and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13197330/380231)